# What should the chat space be called?

Tags: discussion, community, chat

In June 2012, Physics.SE [changed the name of their chat space](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1028/17609) to *The h Bar* (after the reduced Planck constant). In similar spirit, it might be interesting to explore the oppourtunity a  new name for the Philosophy.SE chat room might offer, and evaluate potential alternatives.

The current name *Café Philosophy* is glorious (and venerable, having been the name for several years) -- but perhaps there is a more compelling, spirited or apropos name that could be bestowed upon the space.

What should the chat space be called? What names might help open the space up -- either drive engagement, or help participants feel more welcome and invited to participate? What sort of words should we use to describe the space?

**Please do suggest something, and up- and down-vote suggestions that you like or dislike!** We'll take a look around the 25th or so and see what the community has gravitated around.

Comment: **The contest is completed and the chat room has been renamed.** Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: We actually used to have it called "the Coupling".

Answer (score 3):

**The Symposium**

See [*Symposium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symposium) on Wikipedia. This name has huge connotations in philosophy, so it is particularly apropos. Also, it is definitely more spirited than the current name (although, admittedly, I never frequented a "café philosophy").

Comment: +1 to this; but note symposia are *parties* (events) rather than *rooms* (spaces). This may not be an urgent distinction but it felt relevant to consider in the context.

Comment: Make this a bit more modern and call it The Night Club. Just kidding; +1

Answer (score 1):

**Akademia/The Academy**

Perhaps not as catchy as "The Symposium", but Plato's [Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy) was the first of its kind, and in some sense the first University. It was the first place to foster learning among large groups of students, and since that's what we're trying to do here (and in chat) it may be appropriate.

Comment: Note that there is an [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com). They have a chat room called [Academia](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/academia). Somehow, one or two people might get confused. :)

Answer (score 1):

**The School of Athens**[image: Lots of important people here.]

Maybe that particular phrasing isn't ideal. The School of Athens Lounge? The School of Athens: Online Branch? The School of Athens: Pupil Space?

I can't do puns with philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

**The Psychomanteum**

See [*Psychomanteum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychomanteum) on Wikipedia. The word denotes a mirrored (reflective or echoic) space built as a conduit to other worlds, full of surfaces redoubling the universe. Entry into the chat room should demand an attunement to relationality, especially to the energetics of the space and those inhabiting it; in short it should recall us to gentleness and humility (or if you prefer, respect and love) -- but also demand we permit the space to be transfigured or decoded by the words and ideas (visions and auditions) passing through it.

Comment: Very nicely thought of. Never heard of it before (but that could be just me). One drawback seems to be that the psychomanteum seems to be about _gazing_ (do we want that?) and not communication, except for with the _spiritual realm_. Ingenious, but possibly _literally_ sleep-inducing. So happily voting this one down: -1.

Comment: Thanks! --One quick thought here (about privileging the gaze/speculation) might be about the allegory or parallel between attunement to vision/hearing and to other people (relations). [The other (person) redoubles the universe in a way that challenges my 'repetition'...]

Comment: That leads me to believe that it is too "deep" for a chat room name, which, I think, should be rather obvious, but slightly "in-jokey".

Comment: Yeah, it's probably near-impenetrable. --I guess I wouldn't want to go too "light" on the other hand either; but then the Psychomanteum would be a space flooded with light... :)